# Allocate and free 2D array in C using void

Tags: c, malloc, multidimensional-array

The idea is to use only two functions that can both allocate and free a 2D array of a given data type that is not known at compile-time. The code I have written crashes in the freeing function, but I cannot see why. Here is the code:

```
void** new2DArray(int row, int col, int typeSize){
    void** temp = malloc(sizeof(void*)*row); //EDIT                     
    for (row-=1; row >= 0; row--)                               
        temp[row] = malloc(typeSize*col);
    return temp; 
}


void free2DArray(void** array, int row, int typeSize){
    for (row -= 1; row >= 0; row--)
        free( *(array + row*typeSize) );
     free(array); 
}
```

Where, for a 3x3 array, is would be called like:

```
double** test = (double**) new2DArray(3, 3, sizeof(double));
free2DArray(test, 3, sizeof(double));
```

Is there anything immediately wrong with the freeing function?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to cast `array` in `free2DArray` do a `double **`?

Comment: Of course, if you always were going to use `double` arrays. The point is to have a generalized function in which you could make `int` 2D arrays, `unsigned short`, or anything. I had this all working for just one data type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `free2DArray` looks wrong.  You don't need to know the size of the types; you just free the blocks that you allocated:

```
void free2DArray(void** array, int row){
    for (row -= 1; row >= 0; row--)
        free( array[row] );
     free(array); 
}
```

Comment: I had this originally, but the size of the pointers must be known in order to increment accordingly. Now that I think about it, sizeof(void*) should be the same as any other pointer data type anyway.

Comment: You only need to know `sizeof(void*)` since you only iterate over the first dimension, not the second.

Answer (score 1):

You free column arrays with `free(*(array + row*typeSize));`. However, it should be `free(*(array + row))`, or more concisely, `free(array[row])`. `array + row*typeSize` makes you skip `typeSize` number of column vectors per iteration, and hence, "free" columns that were never allocated.

Comment: I see that mistake now. I meant to do what you have said, rather than increment by the size of the data type in the array.

Comment: It shouldn't be `array + row*sizeof(void*)` because C pointer arithmetic implicitly multiplies the offset by the size of the type to which the pointer points.  It should be just `array + row`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not free it the same way you are allocating it?

```
for (row-=1; row >= 0; row--)                               
        free(array[row]); 
      //free(*(array + row)); <- or the way you are doing it
free(array);
```

Comment: Makes sense now that sizeof(void*) = sizeof(double*) anyway. It would work. I wrote that with the notion that sizeof(void*) would = 1, so I manually added in the increment lengths.